# Saying "The other picture is funnier than THIS ONE"?

Tags: grammaire

How do I say that?
L'autre image est plus drôle que **ce ca**?
I don't understand how to build the last part, please help me.

Comment: L'autre image est plus drôle que celle-ci. When the word is masculine, celui-ci. L'autre livre est plus cher que celui-ci. (also: plural: ceux-ci, masculine plural and celles-ci, feminine plural).

Comment: merci beaucoup!

Comment: @EnmaNii - you might want to upvote answers you like :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The other picture is funnier (than this one)

would be translated as:

> L'autre image est plus amusante (que celle-ci).

"Celui-ci, celle-ci, ceux-ci, celles-ci" are "pronoms démonstratifs" that need to agree in gender and number with the thing they refer to. Here, "image" being feminine, in the singular, "celle-ci" is what you need, and for the plural "celles-ci".

Comment: C'est un forum de traduction maintenant?? Pronouns aren't adjusted, they are used....They are called demonstrative pronouns in English. Talking about mixing it up. [I don't mean confuse by mix up]